# What's the issue with this basic JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to write basic JavaScript which changes the background of a paragraph to yellow and then to pink on click.

```
<p id="foo">Hello, people!</p>
```

and script is:

```
window.onload = function(){
var foo = document.getElementById("foo");
foo.onclick = function(){
        if(foo.style.background!=="yellow")foo.style.background = "yellow";
        if(foo.style.background === "yellow")  foo.style.background = "pink";
};
};
```

The color changes to yellow on first click but it does **not** change to pink when I click again. I can't figure out the problem.

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery?

Comment: Easiest thing is to stick an alert(foo.style.background) or a console.log(foo.style.background) in your onclick function to see what the value is each time.

Comment: Internally, the browser may be using a different representation than the string "yellow" to denote the background.  `console.log(foo.style.background)` to see what it actually is.

Comment: @Tom , @Michael using console.log returned this: `none repeat scroll 0% 0% yellow`

Comment: while in Chrome console.log simply returned `yellow` This seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT: Don't use `background`, use `backgroundColor`

[**Fixed example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ETBxX/1)

```
    if(foo.style.background!=="yellow")foo.style.background = "yellow";
    if(foo.style.background === "yellow")  foo.style.background = "pink";
```

needs to be:

```
    if(foo.style.background!=="yellow")foo.style.background = "yellow";
    else if(foo.style.background === "yellow")  foo.style.background = "pink";
```

because you changing it to yellow, then checking if it's yellow and making it pink

Comment: Well, here's one more reason to use curly braces, line breaks and indentation with if/else blocks.

Comment: No. It does not work even with 'else'. Plus even without else it should do same thing.

Comment: @Jatin: No, it shouldn't. You need to add the `else` and still keep it there, if anything.

Comment: @BoltClock Yes, curly braces and indentation should have been used but that does not seem to be the problem.

Comment: Wait. It works in Chrome but not in FireFox. Can anybody tell why?

Comment: Because firefox addes other values, none repeat scroll 0% 0% yellow

Comment: @Jatin, try clearing the cache. If you hadn't visited with Chrome before, and were testing in firefox, Firefox is probably hanging onto a cached copy.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
if(foo.style.background === "yellow")
```

to this

```
if(foo.style.background == "yellow")
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to the way you're doing your comparison:

```
foo.onclick = function(){
        if(foo.style.background != "yellow") foo.style.background = "yellow";
        if(foo.style.background == "yellow") foo.style.background = "pink";
};
```

Note the use of "!=" and "==" instead of "!==" and "===".

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var foo = document.getElementById("foo");
foo.onclick = function(){
        if(foo.style.background!="yellow")foo.style.background = "yellow";
        else if(foo.style.background =="yellow")  foo.style.background = "pink";
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AvKPE/

```
var foo = document.getElementById("foo");
foo.onclick = function(){
        if(foo.style.backgroundColor!="yellow")foo.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
        else if(foo.style.backgroundColor =="yellow")  foo.style.backgroundColor = "pink";
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AvKPE/2/

Comment: Ok the problem is that firefox returns the whole background property: 0% 0% fixed ... yellow ... Try new link: http://jsfiddle.net/AvKPE/2/